# is there a cross platform way to create a symbolic link in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, cross-platform, symlink

I can use the following p-invoke code on Windows, but is there a cross-platform way to create a symbolic link with .NET Core? (3.0 preview if that matters)

If not, is there a way to p-invoke or similar on linux/ubuntu to do it?

```
public static class PinvokeSymLink
{
    [DllImport( "kernel32.dll" )]
    public static extern bool CreateSymbolicLink( string lpSymlinkFileName, string lpTargetFileName, SymbolicLink dwFlags );

    public enum SymbolicLink
    {
        File = 0,
        Directory = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: I also stumbled on this context, I need symlinks for external HD references.

Comment: @Eugene I think the only way may be to just shell out 'ln -s directory simlin'

Comment: @kenny  did you found the solution

Comment: @chandan I used the shell command in the comment above.

Comment: @Kenny thanks I found the dll Mono.Unix dll with the help of that I was able to achieve   Mono.Unix.UnixSymbolicLinkInfo

Comment: @chandan great ... make it an answer and I'll vote and select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since .NET 6, the [`File.CreateSymbolicLink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.createsymboliclink?view=net-6.0) is available for this purpose.

For the older .NET versions, you can consider p-invoking the [`symlink`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/symlink.2.html) Linux function instead. This worked for me on both Linux and macOS.